# How can we prove that this number is the root of a polynomial of degree 5 with integer coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's take $\alpha = \sqrt[5]{\frac{-75+21\sqrt{10}}{125}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{-75-21\sqrt{10}}{125}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{225+72\sqrt{10}}{125}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{225-72\sqrt{10}}{125}}$.

The goal consists in showing that this number is the root of a polynomial of degree 5 with integers coefficients.

I tried to compute $\alpha^5$ but it's very tedious and I don't find a way to simplify this.

Any help?

Comment: $a:=21 \sqrt{10} / 125$, $b:=72 \sqrt{10} / 125$, $c:= -0.6$

$$ \sqrt[5]{a-c} + \sqrt[5]{-a-c} + \sqrt[5]{3c+b} + \sqrt[5]{3c-b}- \alpha = 0$$ is easier to multiply out. (Or even add d:=1.8 also) $$.$$ And you must multiply it out (I think) $$.$$

Comment: Thanks for this idea, but just getting $\alpha^2$, into $\alpha^5$ is really difficult and this do not simplify when developing.

Comment: Oh i see. There are formulas for the roots, even for fifth degree. I looked for a minute, but just found a method

Comment: Try the formulas for roots of: $Ax^5 + Bx^4.. + F=0$ , assuming B=C=D=E=F=0. In other words, guess that $A \alpha ^5 = 0$ because $\alpha$ is the solution for the fifth-order polynomial $Ax^5=0$. If it works we guessed right

Comment: Except... There are really only two animals in the expression for alpha. One is a= -0.6 (as 0.6 and +/- 1.8.. a and +/- 3a). The other is b=$3 \sqrt{10} / 125$ as +/-7b and +/-24b. So that makes me think maybe **two** of the letters A through F are non-zero, depending upon the formulas for the roots. Must we instead assume B through E are zero? Can we look at the formulas for fifth order solutions and see anything that would give that, or would give the B through F are zero. Good luck

Comment: Also maybe online polynomial calculators. And Finally, back to using a,b,c,d to start multiplying it out, we have (a+b), (a-b), (c+d), (c-d) terms (each $\sqrt[5]{\cdot}$). When you have $(a+b)^3(a-b)^2$ And $(a-b)^5$ and $(a+b)^5$ and 1,4 and 4,1 (and even 2,2 and 1,2 when mixed w (c +/-d) terms, there are patterns and canceling. Might be only way to show not sure. Lotta work. Ok thats all i got good luck again

Comment: Some improvements. Seems that $\alpha^5+15\alpha+12 = 0.$ Found that with Geogebra. But I don't manage to prove this with standard developments of $\alpha^5 = (r+s+u+v)^5$...

Comment: In math and logic, it is a legit proof to guess and then show it’s right. Some may frown on this, and everyone is aware that it might be hard to generalize that method, but it is unequivocally legitimate. Books on differential equations and integration talk about guessing and checking as a method and give some intuition about how one might get good at guessing. Similarly, disproving is often done by showing a single counterexample.

Comment: Meaning you could start with the polynomial you just wrote, and go through the method of determining roots. Either the method setting up a table with some kind of special “division”, is it called “synthetic division” ???  Or the method of the formulae for the roots of a fifth order polynomial. The former method seems more rigorous since you didnt derive the formulae, and is probably easier once you get the idea.